# Clearing input value onclick

Tags: javascript, validation, onclick, reset

I'm looking for some help on clearing the values of my input and text areas onclick after I insert an error message into the value of my inputs and textarea. Here's my code:

HTML

```
<form name="form" action="contact-handler.php" method="post" onsubmit="return contact();">
    <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Name:">
    <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="E-mail:">
    <select name="subject">
            <option value="0">Categories</option>     
            <option value="1">Web Design</option>
        <option value="2">Web Development</option>
        <option value="3">Graphic Design</option>
        <option value="4">Photography / Video</option>
        <option value="5">Marketing</option>
    </select>
    <textarea name="message" placeholder="Message:"></textarea>
    <input class="button" type="submit" value="Send">
</form>
```

JavaSript

```
function contact() {

    var name = form.name.value;
    var email = form.email.value;
    var atPosition = email.indexOf("@");
    var dotPosition = email.lastIndexOf(".");
    var subject = form.subject.value;
    var message = form.message.value;
    var flag = 0;

    // Name
    if(name != "" && name.length > 2 && !/[\d]/.test(name)) {
        flag++;
        form.name.style.border="1px solid #CCC";
    }
    else{
        form.name.style.border="1px solid #D73300";
        form.name.value="Please enter a valid name";
    }
    // Email
    if(email != "" && atPosition > 1 && dotPosition > atPosition + 2 && dotPosition + 2 <= email.length) {
        flag++;
        form.email.style.border="1px solid #CCC";
    }
    else{
        form.email.style.border="1px solid #D73300";
        form.email.value="Please enter a valid email";
    }
    // Subject  
    if(subject > 0) {
        flag++;
        form.subject.style.border="1px solid #CCC";
    }
    else{
        form.subject.style.border="1px solid #D73300";
    }
    // Message
    if(message != "" && message.length > 30) {
        flag++;
        form.message.style.border="1px solid #CCC";
    }
    else{
        form.message.style.border="1px solid #D73300";
        form.message.value="Please enter a valid message";
    }
    // Flag
    if(flag == 4) {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }   
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Change the value of the `placeholder` attribute, not the input value. And use classes for styling:

```
form.element.className = 'error';
form.element.setAttribute('placeholder', "Can I haz a value?");
```

([fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GgNHs/))

A nicer way would be to add the `required="required"` attribute to your form elements, then you can just style them using the [`:invalid`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/%3ainvalid) pseudo-class:

```
input:invalid, textarea:invalid{
  border: ....
}
```

Comment: Your sample code does not reset className for textarea in case of a valid value.

Answer (score 0):

Vanilla JS way:

```
window.onload = function() {
    var form = document.forms["form"];
    var formElems = form.getElementsByTagName('input');
    formElems.concat(form.getElementsByTagName('textarea'));

    for(i=0; i<formElems.length; i++) {
        formElems[i].onclick = function() {
            if(this.style.borderColor == '#CCC') {
               this.value = '';
            }
        }
    }
};
```

put this above your contact function.